# How to move to the next enclosing(div) while scraping a site?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

All the data in is populated from the first table. I cannot move to the next div and get the data of the `td` for each `tr`.

The site: `https://asd.com/page/`

Below is the code that I have written.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
my_url= "https://asd.com/page/asd"
driver.get(my_url)
boxes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-md-4")

companies = []
company = {}
for box in boxes:
    header = box.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"text-primary.text-uppercase")
    company['name']= header.text
    td= box
    company['Type']= td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td").text
    company['Capital']= td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td").text
    company['Address'] = td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td").text
    company['Owner'] = td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td").text
    company['Co-Owner'] = td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td").text
    company['Duration'] = td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td").text
    company['Place'] = td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td").text
    company['Company ID'] = td.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[8]/td").text

    companies.append(company)

    print(company)
```

Comment: .// When xpathing from another element.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I tried that as well. I get the data from the first table in all of the entries as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. You need to add some delay between `driver.get(my_url)` and `boxes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-md-4")` to let the elements loaded before getting the list of all of them.
2. `text-primary.text-uppercase` is actually 2 class names: `text-primary` and `text-uppercase` so you should use XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR to locate element by 2 class names, not by `CLASS_NAME`.
3. In order to locate elements inside another element you should use XPATH starting with a dot `.`
4. Your locators like `//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td` are absolute while they should be calculated based on the parent `box` element.
5. No need to define `td` element, you can use the existing `box` element here.
6. Locators like `//div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td` can and should be improved.
7. You probably will need to scroll to boxes while iterating over them.
8. I think `company = {}` should be defined inside the loop.
   This should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
my_url= "https://monentreprise.bj/page/annonces"
driver.get(my_url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "col-md-4")))
time.sleep(2)
boxes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-md-4")

companies = []
for box in boxes:
    actions.move_to_element(box).perform()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    company = {}
    header = box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//h5[@class='text-primary text-uppercase']")
    company['name']= header.text
    company['Objet']= box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[1]/td").text
    company['Capital']= box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[2]/td").text
    company['Siège Social'] = box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[3]/td").text
    company['Gérant'] = box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[4]/td").text
    company['Co-Gérant'] = box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[5]/td").text
    company['Durée'] = box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[6]/td").text
    company['Dépôt'] = box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[7]/td").text
    company['Immatriculation RCCM'] = box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//tr[8]/td").text

    companies.append(company)

    print(company)
```

Comment: This works better than before but only extracts from 15 out of the 100 boxes available.

Comment: what is the length of `boxes` list? can you see? What happens after the 15 boxes data extracted?

Comment: Edit: Turns out all tables did not have the same number of ```boxes```. Needed some ```if-else``` to make it work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to loop through the pages?
I tried to loop through the xpath of the pagination but the element is always clickable.
Cannot stop on the last page.

Comment: Generally it should be possibly. Please ask a new, separate question for that and I will try helping there too if I will can

Comment: I have added the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71480545/how-to-stop-the-selenium-webdriver-after-reaching-the-last-page-while-scraping-t