# How to stop the selenium webdriver after reaching the last page while scraping the website?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The amount of data(number of pages) on the site keeps changing and I need to scrape all the pages looping through the pagination.
Website: `https://monentreprise.bj/page/annonces`

Code I tried:

```
xpath= "//*[@id='yw3']/li[12]/a"        
while True:
    next_page = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,xpath)
    if len(next_page) < 1:
        print("No more pages")
        break
    else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
        print('ok')
```

`ok` is printed continuously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. `//*[@id='yw3']/li[12]/a` is not a correct locator for the `next` pagination button.
2. The better indication for the last page reached state here will be to validate if this css_locator based element `.pagination .next` contains `disabled` class.
3. You have to scroll the page down before clicking the next page button
4. You have to add a delay after clicking on the pagination button. Otherwise this will not work.
   This code worked for me:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
my_url = "https://monentreprise.bj/page/annonces"
driver.get(my_url)
next_page_parent = '.pagination .next'
next_page_parent_arrow = '.pagination .next a'
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    parent = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,next_page_parent)
    class_name = parent.get_attribute("class")
    if "disabled" in class_name:
        print("No more pages")
        break
    else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_page_parent_arrow))).click()
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print('ok')
```

The output is:

```
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
No more pages
```

Comment: Even after using CSS  infinite ```ok``` printed as output. Also, next page is not reached.
 
I tried recording it with Katalon Recorder. It records ```find_element(By.LINK_TEXT)```. Yet I cannot reproduce it using link text in my code.

Comment: OK, I will try to debug it

Comment: See my updated answer. It works

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked with two caveats. One, I had to add sleep time (due to my machine probably). Two, I only got 12 ```ok``` printed.

Comment: Great! The required pauses indeed may vary due to internet speed etc. I got the output as I presented here.

Comment: I'm happy I could help you, my friend :) In case you will have more questions don't hesitate to ask them. But please provide the essential details. This question could not be answered without the actual link to the page you are asking about...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242981/discussion-between-professional-learner-and-prophet).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72054468/how-to-capture-data-from-table-using-selenium-python

Answer (score 2):

Because the condition `if len(next_page)<1` is always False.

For instance I tried the url [monentreprise.bj/page/annonces?Company_page=99999999999999999999999](https://monentreprise.bj/page/annonces?Company_page=99999999999999999999999999999999999&ajax=annonces-list) and it gives the page 13 which is the last page

What you could try maybe is checking if the "next page" button is disabled
[image]